# Site list does weird things with Stack Overflow

Tags: bug, stack-exchange-button, top-bar

The site listing for Stack Overflow looks odd in my site list, perhaps because of the weird main-meta relationship that Stack Overflow and Meta Stack Overflow have.

Assuming the indentation is just there supposed to indicate the relationship (which admittedly is a bit unclear), could the reputation at least be displayed in this case since it's different than on the corresponding linked site?

[image: site list with weird SO display]